# Mostrar datos de una tabla sqlserver en php

Tags: php, sql-server

Logre conectar mi base de datos con php, pero no logro visuzalizar los datos de X tabla en mi proyecto.

Les dejo el codigo:

```
    <?php
    $serverName = "*******"; 
    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"*****", "UID"=>"******", "PWD"=>"********");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
    if( $conn ) {
        echo "Conexión establecida. ". "<img src=\"online.png\" border='0' width='30' height='30'>";
    }else{
        echo "Conexión no se pudo establecer.". "<img src=\"offline.png\" border='0' width='30' height='30'>";
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
$sql = ("SELECT * FROM mi_tabla");
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
```

Comment: Hola, pero en tu código no veo ningún `SELECT` tal vez te hizo falta agregar eso a tu código

Comment: Tengo esto, pero nose si estoy en lo correcto?
$sql = ("SELECT * FROM mi_tabla");
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );

Comment: Que mas me falta para poder vizualizar los datos?

Comment: ¿Puedes confirmar que la tabla a la que accedes realmente se llama mi_tabla? Si es así te recomiendo encarecidamente cambiarle el nombre... Aparte de eso, ¿te sale algún mensaje de error?

Comment: Ya cambie el nombre, y no logro visualizar los datos